# How to add Dependency to Azure App service

Tags: python, r, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I have a Spring project and thinking of deploying it in Azure App service.But I need to have python and R server as dependencies.Is it possible to add python and R as extensions in an App Service.

I scrolled through most of the documentation but can't seem to figure out a way to do so.

Edit:
I figured python is present in the virtual mahchine by default and it is possible to add python dependencies.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2015/06/29/install-native-python-modules-on-azure-web-apps-api-apps/

But I still can't figure out how to install R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add these extensions for your Web App. Follow the below steps.
Select Web App -> Development Tools -> Extensions -> click Add -> Choose the available extensions ->  Accept legal terms -> Ok

[image]

[image]

You can also add these extensions from the [Kudu Console](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console).

Select extensions from the gallery and install.

[image]

Hope this helps.